# Composer auto generated wrong path

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I am building a website with Laravel 5.
Laravel is using Composer as dependency management.

Whenever I run `composer dump-autoload` the autoload classes are generated.
Unfortunately the path in two of these files are wrong.

I am using one Seed class and some migrations within Laravel which is located in `database/seeds` respectively `database/migrations`.

The generated paths to all classes (migrations, seeds) below the database folder is wrong.
The path looks like `$baseDir . '/atabase/migrations/2017_02_02_153131_create_cards_table.php'`
As you can see the "d" from "database" is missing.

As far as I know the autoload classes are defined in the `composer.json` file.
But here it seems to be correct:

```
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

The migration is working, but the seeds are not.
When I do a search&replace and correct the path everything is fine unless I do `composer dump-autoload`

I am developing on a Windows 10 machine with Laravel 5.4.8 and Composer 1.3.2.

---

Edit:
Here is the output of `composer dump-autoload -vvv`

```
PS C:\Users\phoef\Documents\Projekte\CardViewer> composer dump-autoload -vvv 
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file C:\Users\phoef\AppData\Local\Temp\composer-cacert-    300c74d6960d46715ffed607c8e36acfa7cbcad49862bb1b67d3c43dea9bfb40.pem: valid
Executing command (C:\Users\phoef\Documents\Projekte\CardViewer): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Reading C:/Users/phoef/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Loading config file C:/Users/phoef/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Reading C:\Users\phoef\Documents\Projekte\CardViewer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Reading C:/Users/phoef/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Running 1.3.2 (2017-01-27 18:23:41) with PHP 7.1.1 on Windows NT / 10.0
Generating autoload files
```

The two files containg the wrong path are: `autoload_classmap.php` and `autoload_static.php`.

---

Edit 2:
Please find below the complete `composer.json`

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `composer dump-autoload -vvv` to get more information about what is doing.

Comment: Added the output of `compower dump-autoload -vvv` to the post. Thanks.

Comment: I've the same error and i can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The seeds and migrations live in the `database/` directory (from project root), not inside `app/`. Do you'll have `database/seeds/CardsTableSeeder.php`, for example.

Did you create them using `artisan`?

`php artisan make:migration create_cards_table`

`php artisan make:seed CardsTableSeeder`

It's not required to do it this way but it's handy to be sure you get them in the right directory.

Here's my `autoload`, you're missing the `psr-4` key.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

I have noidea why it's doing `atabase`, sorry

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo in my post. The seeds and migrations are located in `database/seeds` and `database/migrations` not below the `app` folder. I've corrected this in my post.

Yes I created the seeds and the migrations with artisan with exactly these two commands you mentioned. 

Again, sorry for not posting the psr-4 key. The `autoload` part in the `composer.json` is exactly looking the same as yours.

Answer (score -3):

You are doing something wrong. You need to reset project and start from start.

Comment: the project is actually clean. I started the project 3 days ago. I noticed this behaviour after creating the first seed.

Comment: share your composer file.

Comment: I added the complete `composer.json` to my original post.

Comment: Try with `--no-dev` flag and share result.

Comment: I tried executing `composer dump-autoload --no-dev` and also `composer dump-autoload -vvv --no-dev` but the result is the same as I've posted. I do not see any additional output based on the `--no-dev` flag. Can you please explain the command in detail?

Comment: I was trying to test problem is with development PSR-4 or not. --no-dev means no development packages and settings.

Can you please tell me what IDE you are using and do one additional step uninstall composer and then reinstall again.

Comment: I just deleted the `composer.phar` file and the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Composer` folder. Then, I downloaded the Windows installer from the offical composer website and installed it again. The behaviour is still the same: Running `composer dump-autoload` generated wrong paths. I am using Visual Studio Code as IDE. But there is no difference between calling `composer` through the embedded PowerShell of Visual Studio Code or the "normal" PowerShell application.

Comment: It is really complicated, did you try without visual studio?

Comment: Yes I tried all the commands in the CMD and PowerShell. As Visual Studio Code ist just an editor I do not think that it has any influence. I've set up the project before through the CMD (not within Visual Studio Code).

Comment: If it is behaving same in new project also then. It is something malfunctioning and you need to degrade composer and do not use or create with MS.VS.